# Line break issue using Bootstrap 5 on Safari (IPhone 12)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a small site using Bootstrap 5. And when I've been testing the mobile part using the dev tools in Firefox (IPhone 12/13 selected).

And that breaks the line way to early instead. Surely "558/" should fit. And when I try it on my Iphone 12 it doesn't seem to care about the padding to the right of the container to determine the word break.

Here's how it looks on my phone:

[image]

Here how it looks (and should look) in the dev tools for Firefox Iphone 12/13:

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="content-container" class="container-xxl mx-auto p-4 bg-white">
  <main>
    <div class="row p-xl-4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="mb-5 col-sm-12 col-md-8 p-4" style="border: 2px solid red">
          www.trrrrrrrrrr.co.uk/rrrrrrr/558/rrrwwwwrrrrr-rrrrrr
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

How can I adjust this so it breaks right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-break` class on the div

```
<div class="text-break mb-5 col-sm-12 col-md-8 p-4" style="border: 2px solid red">
      www.trrrrrrrrrr.co.uk/rrrrrrr/558/rrrwwwwrrrrr-rrrrrr
</div>
```

Or add custom css

```
.classname{word-break: break-all;}
```

hope it works for you